# Variable and domain_variable have stuffed up my menus

Tags: configuration

Variable and domain_variable modules fixed the front page issue, so I am now able to have two unique front pages. However, it has broken the main menus. I've had the original Main Menu displaying on the default domain, and created a new menu for the Secondary domain. The new menu was displaying fine, until I installed the domain_variable module and set the front pages.

My issue is: the Main Menu is being displayed on both the domains, even though I've got a different menu which should be displaying on the secondary domain.

How do I get the menus to display correctly? How do I get the secondary meny to display on the secondary domain (as the main menu across the top)?

Comment: Could you phrase it in a form of a question? like "how to ... using ...?"

Comment: I mean, this situation is tied to your setup, and that's what we can't access. Could you make it general / universal a bit? I mean, I think I had similar setup but nothing like that happened.